# Redis to listen keys and events

Tags: redis

I have this below nodejs code to connect redis, create a key (ex: myKey) and to listen events. Please also note that, I have enabled the notifications (CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events KEA)

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient(); //A
const events= ['__keyspace@0__:myKey', '__keyevent@0__:set:myKey'];

client.set('myKey', 20, redis.print);

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.subscribe(events);
  client.on('message', function (keySpace, event) {
    console.log(`Event (${event}), Key:${key}`);
  });    
});
```

I have seen lots of example where, a separate redis subscriber client gets created and listen to the events.
Can I use the same client (//A) to listen the events that will act a subscriber too?